# Remove certain extensions from filename with multiple extensions

Tags: string, matlab, file, split

I can get the filename without extension using `fileparts`

```
>> f = '/foo/bar/file.gz'
>> [~,filename,~] = fileparts(f)
filename =

    'file'
```

However if the file has multiple extensions, only the last one will be removed

```
>>f = '/foo/bar/file.gz.tar'
>>[~,filename,~] = fileparts(f)
filename =

    'file.gz'
```

I know it's ambiguous what the file extension could be with multiple dots, but is there a way I can specify, for example, that both `.gz` and `.gz.tar` should be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always search for dots manually:

```
[~,filename,~] = fileparts(f);
i = find(filename == '.', 1, 'first');
if ~isempty(i)
    filename = filename(1:i - 1);
end
```

Or you can iterate `fileparts` until it stops changing the name:

```
[~, filename, ~] = fileparts(f);
prev = '';
while ~strcmp(prev, filename)
    prev = filename;
    [~, filename, ~] = fileparts(prev);
end
```

If you are looking to remove an exact extension, it's much simpler. Just check if the name ends with that sequence, and strip off as many characters as you need. For the `.tar.gz` example:

```
ext = '.tar.gz';
n = numel(ext);
if numel(f) >= n && all(f(end - n + 1:end) == ext)
    f = f(1:end - n);
end
[~, filename, ext] = fileparts(f);
filename = [filename ext];
```

Comment: thanks @MadPhysicist, but what if the file looks like `file.abc.gz.tar` and I want to retrieve `file.abc`? How can I specify that I only want specific extensions to be removed (for example either `.gz.tar` or `.gz`)?

Comment: @HappyPy: That is quite impractical. You’d have to explicitly list all possible extensions, but there is no way you can list them all.

Comment: @HappyPy [`.abc`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alembic_(computer_graphics)) is also an extension

Comment: @HappyPy. Hopefully the update I made answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

This removes all extensions:

```
f = '/foo/bar/file.gz.tar';
path = fileparts(f);                % get folder path
fileWithExt = erase(f,[path '/']);  % erase folder path from full path
fparts = strsplit(fileWithExt,'.'); % split string at dot
file = fparts{1};                   % get first entry
```

This only removes extensions of choice:

```
f = '/foo/bar/file.gz.tar.abc.xyz';
exts = {'tar','xyz'};               % extensions to remove

path = fileparts(f);                % get folder path
fileWithExt = erase(f,[path '/']);  % erase folder path from full path
fparts = strsplit(fileWithExt,'.'); % split string at dot
mask = ismember(fparts,exts);       % mask of extensions to remove
file = strjoin(fparts(~mask),'.');  % stitch string back together
```